# Was the "polynomial remainder theorem" known before polynomial long division was discovered?

Tags: mathematics, elementary-algebra

Nowadays we can easily prove the following fact using polynomial long division:

> If $a$ is a root of the polynomial $f$, then there exists a polynomial $g$ such that $f(x) = (x - a)g(x)$.

I can't imagine how to prove this without polynomial long division. I have two questions:

1. Who invented polynomial long division, and when?
2. Was the above theorem known before the discovery of polynomial long division? If so, how was it proven?

Comment: Actually the first time I learned about this factorisation it was proved without the polynomial long division. You basically say that $f(x) = f(x) - f(a)$ and try to factorize that explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Up to notational conventions polynomial division algorithm was first described by an Arabic mathematician al-Samawal (1130-1180), who can also be credited with defining what we call polynomials today, see [Who invented short and long division?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/who-invented-short-and-long-division/2108#2108) In light of that the factorization theorem does not predate polynomial division.